# Mit welchen Verben kann man das Partizip II verwenden?

Tags: grammar-identification, tense, past-participle

> Ich habe dir gesagt, nach Hause zu gehen.
>   Ich habe gehofft, dir geholfen zu haben.

Warum ist nur der zweite Satz korrekt?

> Ich hoffe, dass Sie gut an meiner Schule angekommen sind, ohne Probleme gehabt zu haben.
>   Ich hätte mir die Haare selber schneiden sollen, anstatt sie schneiden zu lassen.

Warum kann man nicht beim 2. Satz sagen: *anstatt sie schneiden gelassen zu haben*?

Answer (score 2):

Der erste Satz ist auch nicht unbedingt falsch, nur unglücklich. Wenn man das "gesagt" durch "befohlen" ersetzt, erscheint es mir als korrekt.

Beim zweiten Beispiel benutzt du das falsche Verb. Nicht "lassen" sondern "schneiden" muss umgesetzt werden:
"Ich hätte mir die Haare selber schneiden sollen, anstatt geschnitten zu bekommen."

(Falls ich mich irre, berichtigt mich bitte)

Comment: Erster Satz: Wieso "auch"?

Comment: "Der zweite Satz ist korrekt." "Der erste Satz ist 'auch' korrekt."   
Bezieht sich auf die Aussage in der Frage.

Answer (score 2):

Das Partizip II kann man bei allen Verben verwenden. Ohne ein Partizip II kann man die Zeitformen *Perfekt, Plusquamperfekt* und *Futur II* nicht bilden.

Als Beispiel mögen hier die Verben »schlafen« und »landen« dienen, deren Partizip II »geschlafen« und »gelandet« sind.

- **Perfekt**
  Bildung des Perfekts:

  - Eine Präsens-Form des Hilfsverbs *»haben«* oder *»sein«* plus
  - das **Partizip II** des Vollverbs:

  > Ich habe **geschlafen.**
  >   Ich bin **gelandet.**
- **Plusquamperfekt**
  Bildung des Plusquamperfekts:

  - Eine Präteritum-Form des Hilfsverbs *»haben«* oder *»sein«* plus
  - das **Partizip II** des Vollverbs:

  > Ich hatte **geschlafen.**
  >   Ich war **gelandet.**
- **Futur II**
  Bildung des Futur II:

  - Eine Präsens-Form des Hilfsverbs *»werden«* plus
  - das **Partizip II** des Vollverbs plus
  - die infinitive Form von *»haben«* oder *»sein«*:

  > Ich werde **geschlafen** haben.
  >   Ich werde **gelandet** sein.

Da man alle Verben in allen Zeitformen verwendet kann, kann man auch von allen Verben das Partizip II bilden.

Answer (score 0):

Beim ersten Beispiel klingt der erste Satz bestenfalls ja ein bisschen seltsam. Das liegt daran, dass man hier eigentlich einen Nebensatz erwartet. Der Ausdruck "nach Hause zu gehen" ist aber kein (Neben)satz (es fehlt ein Subjekt). Man bildet den Satz einfach wie bei indirekter Rede: "Ich habe dir gesagt, dass du nach Hause gehst (gehen solltest)" oder, im alltäglichen Deutsch, "Ich habe dir gesagt, (kurze Pause) du gehst nach Hause".

Im zweiten Satz nimmt das Verb "hoffen" nicht unbedingt einen Satz als Objekt. In diesem Fall ist das Objekt kein Neben(satz) sondern der Sachverhalt jemandem geholfen zu haben.

Beim zweiten Beispiel kommt "lassen" als Modalverb vor.  Deswegen setzt man in diesem Fall [kein Partizip](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv).